# Matplotlib, settng in-plot text with plt.text() with pandas time series data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Matplotlib allows one to set text within the plot inself with `matplotlib.axes.Axes.text()`.

I am plotting Pandas Series data, so the x-axis are dates.

```
Datetime
2014-11-08    345
2014-11-09    678 
2014-11-10    987
2014-11-11    258
Freq: W-SUN, dtype: int64
```

If I wanted to add text add location `(x,y) = (2014-11-08, 345)`, how could I do this? `2014-11-08` is not actually the x value on the x-axis. How can I find this location?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are several options. You can either use the values from the Series objects' index, `date` or `datetime` objects from the Python standard library's `datetime` or pandas' `Timestamp` object to set the x-axis location of a label on a time-series plot.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = pd.Series({Timestamp('2014-11-08 00:00:00'): 345,
    Timestamp('2014-11-09 00:00:00'): 678,
    Timestamp('2014-11-10 00:00:00'): 987,
    Timestamp('2014-11-11 00:00:00'): 258})

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
s.plot(ax=ax)

i = 0
ax.text(s.index[i], s.iloc[i], "Hello")
ax.text(dt.date(2014, 11, 9), 500, "World")
ax.text(Timestamp("2014-11-10"), 777, "!!!")

plt.show()
```

[image: The result]